# Laravel 3 Eloquent ORM usage

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I have the following code which works but doesn't seem to follow the laravel eloquent way:

```
Article::left_join('images', 'articles.id', '=', 'images.article_id')
            ->join('article_category', 'articles.id', '=', 'article_category.article_id')
            ->where('article_category.category_id', '=', $category_id)
            ->get();
```

I have 4 tables; articles and categories which have a many to many relationship with each other, a pivot table article_category table which holds the article id and category id and an image table which has one to one relationship with an article.

I setup my models as:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    public static function get_articles($category_id) {
        return static::find($category_id)->has_many_and_belongs_to('Article');
    }

class Article extends Eloquent {
    public function categories() {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Category');
    }

    public function image() {
        return $this->has_one('Image');
    }
```

However I can't seem to get all three bits of info together. I can do:

```
Category::get_articles($current_category)->get();
```

To get all articles in a given category but I can't seem to get the image for the article, there seems to be nothing I can chain onto? Unless I'm doing it incorrectly? Is there a trick I'm missing?

I even tried the stripped down version from the docs:

```
foreach (Article::with('image')->get() as $article) {
    echo $article->image->foo;
}
```

However I get an error: Trying to get property of non-object, even though var_dump shows $article->image is an object! Weird.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have not setup a model for the image table, do that. The ORM needs the model there so it knows what 'Image' refers to.

Can you get the category information using the ::with method or is that troublesome too?